# How can I copy the contents of a child folder to its parent folder using command line?

Tags: command-line, cp

I have this directory structure:

```
parent_folder/child_folder/
```

I want to copy the contents of the child folder to the parent folder, but I don't know how to do it with `cp`.

Comment: i have found it here, its working
https://superuser.com/questions/151504/move-folder-contents-into-parent-folder-linux-commandline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to copy all content then run the command below

```
cp path-of-child-folder/* path-of-parent-folder
```

If particular content then run the command

`cp path-of-child-folder/content path-of-parent-folder`

Comment: FYI this does NOT work if the child folder contains hidden files (like .git)

Comment: Use `cp -r path-of-child-folder/. path-of-parent-folder` to include hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple sequence of commands (assuming that `parent_folder` is an absolute path):

```
cd parent_folder
cp -R child_folder/* .
```

The second command is the essential one.
And if you want to remove the `child_folder` after the copy procedure, use

```
rm -R child_folder
```

Now your `parent_folder` contains both the contents of itself plus the contents of `child_folder`.

*Note that this doesn't flatten the directory structure on the `child_folder`.*

Answer (score 0):

In zsh:

```
cp -r child/*(D) parent/
```

This covers hidden files, as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple as that:

```
cp -R file_name $(pwd)/../
```

This command will copy your file, and it will print the current directory and
go to the parent folder.

If you want to access the grandparent folder, you just need to add one more "../"

EXAMPLE:

To copy the file to the parent folder:

```
cp -R file_name $(pwd)/../
```

To copy the file to the grandparent folder:

```
cp -R file_name $(pwd)/../../
```

To copy the file to the great-grandparent folder  :

```
cp -R file_name $(pwd)/../../../
```

etc.

Comment: You don't even need this `$(pwd)` stuff. After all, you're already in that directory. `..` by itself will refer to that directory's parent directory (and so on) just fine.